# What does this Verilog module do?

Tags: verilog

What does the following Verilog module do?

```
module mystery(r, a);
  parameter IW = 16, OW = 32;
  input  [IW-1:0] a;
  output [OW-1:0] r;

  wire   [OW-1:0] al;

  assign al = {{(OW-IW){a[IW-1]}} , a};
  assign r  = (al << 2) + (al << 1) + al;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

`IW` and `OW` are parameter which define the input and output bit widths.

We have a 16 bit inout and a 32 bit output, with `al` an internal 32 bit value. Widths are often declared as 0 to WIDTH-1. instead of 1 to WIDTH, this is why we have`[IW-1:0]` and `[OW-1:0]`.

Verilog has a bit replication function `{ NUMBER { VALUE }}` This replicates the VALUE a NUMBER of times.

Verilog also has bit concatenation `{VALUE_A, VALUE_B}`.

We can also do part selects of an array a[0] for the LSB (least significant bit), a[1:0] for the least two significant bits or a[IW-1] for the MSB (most significant bit).

The MSB of a signed value contains the signed information, sometimes referred to as the sign bit.

These three rules are combined in this instruction:

```
assign al = {  {(OW-IW){a[IW-1]}}, a  };
```

It is taking the MSB (Sign) of a and replicating it, the difference between OW and IW ie 16 times. Then concatenating this with `a`. This pattern is often used as it is **sign extending a**.

### Part 2

`<<` is a bit shift to the left. this is the same as multiplying by 2. Two shifts to the left (`<<2`) is the same as multiplying by 4.

So to leave some thing for you to work out the last line is equivalent to :

```
assign r  = (al*4) + (al*2) + (al*1);
```

Remember `al` is just a sign extension of the input `a`. `al` holds the same numerical values.

Answer (score 0):

module mystery(r, a);

parameter IW = 16, OW = 32;

input  [IW-1:0] a;

output [OW-1:0] r;

wire   [OW-1:0] al;

assign al = {{(OW-IW){a[IW-1]}} , a};

assign r  = (al << 2) + (al << 1) + al;

endmodule

Line by Line Explanation:
Line-1: defines a module ***mystery*** with two signals - *r,a*

Line-2: defines two parameters, IW and OW, with corresponding values as indicated against them in code. Parameters are like constants in Verilog.

Line-3,4: declares **r** as output and **a** as input; these are vectored nets, input a going from [16-1:0] i.e. 15 down_to 0 (its a 16 bit vector)
and output r going from [32-1:0] i.e. 31 down_to 0 (its a 32 bit vector)
Notice that values of parameters IW and OW gets replaced by 16 and 32 resp.

Line-5 declares a wire of net datatype, *al* vectored , of size 31:0 i.e. 32 bits

Line-6 does a concurrent assignment to the net *al*

(OW-IW)=(32-16)=16

[IW-1]=[16-1]=15

{} in verilog denotes concatenation operation, so we would have,

{{16{a[15]}},a}    i.e. 15th bit of 'a' is replicated 16 times and the result is concatenated with original 16 bit vector 'a' thus leading a 32 bit vector *al*

Line-7 it performs left shift operation on al by 2 and 1 and adds these shifted values as depicted in code.

so it can be viewed as:

r=(al*4)+(al*2)+(al);

left shift by *n* indicates multiplying the value by *2n*

Hope I was able to clear your query! :)
Keep coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

This line:  assign al = {{(OW-IW){a[IW-1]}} , a}
sign-extends the input word by repeating its leftmost (sign) bit the number of times necessary to make al the same size as the output.

This line: assign r = (al << 2) + (al << 1) + al;
adds (4x input value) + (2x input value) + 1x input value
taking advantage of the previous sign extension.
IF the output word size is not sufficiently larger than input word size, it is possible that this addition could overflow.

Thus this module asynchronously multiplies a signed input by a fixed value of 7.